# How to start Samsung IAM & EMM app to show the app that user should install

Tags: android, samsung-knox

Following code start samsung IAM & EMM app that is installed on the device

```js
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.samsung.knoxemm.mdm");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

The problem is that I want to show an app just like open playstore with

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
```

Thanks in advance for any information and suggestion